# Рассчитать "y" при определенном "x" при известных текущей позиции и скорости объекта

Tags: геометрия, физика, вычислительная-геометрия

Есть объект, который находится на координатах "x": 200, "y": 200. Перемещается со скоростью 140 по оси "y" и 200 по оси "x". Необходимо определить, какова будет его "y" координата, когда его "x" координата будет равна 570. Подскажите алгоритм поиска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотрите сами - уравнения движения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, все параметры понятны? Находите момент времени *t*, когда *x* равно 570, подставляете во второе уравнение, находите *y*. Задача для 7, ну, максимум 8 класса средней школы...